# C# run time customization of ToolStrip

Tags: c#, .net, toolstrip

With Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, is there any native .NET functionality which allows for user customization of a Tool Bar? I.e., after the application is running, allowing the user to right click on the toolbar and select some form of a 'Customize' command. Allowing the user to hide/show and rearrange buttons and save the user settings as a preference somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is not built-in to .Net.

If you're willing to spend money, I recommend [DevExpress XtraBars](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Bars/index.xml).  (No, I'm not affiliated with them)